# Group of columns as unique key in Mysql but using timestamp as a day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns (
    id (int 11)
    announce_id (int 11)
    inserted_at ( current_timestamp)
)

I would like to know If its possible to create an index that counts only inserted_at as the day on the insertion. The column `inserted_at` a timestamp. I need to create an index with inserted_at and announce_id. I tried:
 
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX announce_inserted
ON user_announce_access (announce_id, DATE(inserted_at))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.7 or higher you can create a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) that contains the date, and then use that in the index.

```
ALTER TABLE user_announce_access
ADD inserted_date AS DATE(inserted_at);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX announce_inserted
ON user_announce_access (announce_id, inserted_date);
```

Comment: before MySQL 5.7, we could create a regular column named `inserted_date`, and we could make use of BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to automatically populate that from the value provided for the `inserted_at` column +10